# aptdaemon folder in the home directory with debconf.socket

Tags: apt, services, sockets

I have been searching and browsing for a long time and have not been able to find an answer for my question.
I found 2 files in y home folder that I've never created.

```
aptdaemon-tw2bIZ
aptdaemon-_yMo_z
```

There is a socket inside of them `debconf.socket` .

Is there any chance that they are related to  *** USN-2648-1: Aptdaemon vulnerability *** discussed here [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2648-1/) ?

Is it safe to delete them and how to prevent their creation in the future?
Someone have any clue ?

Comment: That USN is for versions 12.04 and 14.04. If you run 16.04 then no. If you run 12.04 and 14.04 and never updated in the past year (...) then yes otherwise no. Can't find anything but 1 post on UF regarding "aptdaemon"  and this problem D: I would say: rename them 1st, then check if updates and installing software still works. If so delete them :) Those do not belong in your /home/

Comment: Actually I'm running 14.04  ...  > Linux 4.4.0-38-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu . Updated recently  the kernel . I'll try that Thanks @Rinzwind

Comment: Everything sames working fine thanks. I'm still wondering how they've been created, is there any chance that an `apt-get clear ` would have trigger that ?!